# Qt : Reading the text file and Displaying in LineEdit

Tags: ruby, qt, methods, qlineedit, qtruby

I have an input file and a  batch file. When the batch file is executed using the System command, 
a corresponding outfile is generated.

Now I want a particular text (position 350 to 357) from that outfile to be displayed on to my lineedit widget

Here is that part of my code:

```
 system("C:/ORG_Class0178.bat")
```

Now the outfile will be generated

```
 File.open("C:/ORG_Class0178_out.txt", 'r').each do |line|
    var = line[350..357]
    puts var
```

# To test whether the file is being read.

```
    @responseLineEdit = Qt::LineEdit.new(self)
    @responseLineEdit.setFont Qt::Font.new("Times NEw Roman", 12)
    @responseLineEdit.resize 100,20
    @responseLineEdit.move 210,395 
    @responseLineEdit.setText("#{var}")
 end
```

When I do test whether the file is being read using puts statement, I get the exact required output in editor. However, the same text is not being displayed on LineEdit. Suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: A wired observation here. It works fine when I try to read the input file and display it , however it does not work with the output file. The puts statement does  give the answer in editor confirming that output file does contain the required text. I am confused over this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code fragments shown.

Note that `var` is a local variable. Are the second and third code fragments in the same context? If they are in the same method, and `var` is not touched in-between, it will work.

If the fragments belong to different methods of the same class, than an instance variable (`@var`) will solve the problem.

If all that does not help, use [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/) to chase the problem. Follow the link to find the pre-requisites and how to use. Place `binding.pry` in your code, and your program will stop at that line. Then inspect what your variables are doing.

Comment: I have actually tried the code in your third fragment. It does work. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: ^1 for bindings.pry , was able to find out the problem

Answer (score 0):

try 'rb' instead of 'r'

```
File.open("C:/ORG_Class0178_out.txt", 'rb').each do |line|
    var = line[350..357]
    puts var
```